# How to use SQL-SUM in Symfony-Easyadmin?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

In Symfony I have created a CrudController, and overridden the methods "configureFields", and "createIndexQueryBuilder".
This is how the implementation looks like:

```
 public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('account', 'Customer')->setColumns(4),
            TextField::new('organizationIdentifier', 'organization identifier')->setColumns(4),
            IntegerField::new('countOfChargableIrdis', 'count of orders')->setColumns(4),
        ];
    }

public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
    {
        /** @var EntityRepository $entityRepository */
        $entityRepository = $this->get(EntityRepository::class);
        $queryBuilder = $entityRepository->createQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);

        $queryBuilder->andWhere('entity.bookedAt IS NULL');
        $queryBuilder->addGroupBy('entity.organizationIdentifier');

        return $queryBuilder;
    }
```

and this is how the table looks like:

[image]

**Now I want to sum up "count of orders" of the grouped data, and display the result.**

So I want to do something like:

```
$queryBuilder->addSelect('entity.account');
        $queryBuilder->addSelect('entity.organizationIdentifier');
        $queryBuilder->addSelect('SUM(entity.countOfChargableIrdis) AS countOfChargableIrdis');

$queryBuilder->andWhere('entity.bookedAt IS NULL');
        $queryBuilder->addGroupBy('entity.organizationIdentifier');
```

But so I always get the following error message:

> Cannot read property "id" from an array. Maybe you intended to write
> the property path as "[id]" instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell doctrine to ignore that column thanks to the keyword `HIDDEN` like this:

```
$queryBuilder->addSelect('SUM(entity.countOfChargableIrdis) AS HIDDEN countOfChargableIrdis');
```

Otherwise, doctrine will find a new field and would not be able to return an object, so will go for an array instead. That is what will get you this error.

Example in documentation: https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields.html#unmapped-fields

Comment: I do exactly the same, but I am getting no association, in entity. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77661460/easyadmin-field-sotring-faild-with-no-association