# Easyadmin field sotring faild with no association

Tags: symfony, doctrine, easyadmin

I have a `Site` entity, and a `Zone` entity. Zones has a many to one relations to sites.

When I listing sites, I'd like to add a new column: `Count of zones` to show, how many zones related to a site. So, I've added this to `Site` entity:

```
public function getZonesCount(): int
{
    return $this->zones->count();
}
```

In the crud controller, I've also added a new field:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    $fields = parent::configureFields($pageName);
    $fields[] = NumberField::new('zones_count', 'Count of Zones')->setSortable(true);
    return $fields;
}
```

It works great, the only problem is that, it is not sortable, because I am getting this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 58 near 'zones_count ': Error: Class App\Entity\Site has no field or association named zones_count

of course, because it is not in the query.

So, based on the [documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields.html#unmapped-fields), I've extended my `queryBuilder`:

```
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(
    SearchDto $searchDto,
    EntityDto $entityDto,
    FieldCollection $fields,
    FilterCollection $filters
): QueryBuilder {
    $queryBuilder = parent::createIndexQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
    if (0 === count($searchDto->getSort())) {
        $queryBuilder->innerJoin('entity.zones', 'z');
        $queryBuilder->addSelect('COUNT(z.site) AS HIDDEN zones_count');
        $queryBuilder->addGroupBy('entity.id, entity.name, entity.address');
        $queryBuilder->addOrderBy('zones_count', 'DESC');
    }
    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

Query runs prefectly, I've checked. Getting the same error.

I've also tried to use `AssociatedField`, same error. I do not want to modify my `Site` entity, anyhow, `getZonesCount` should work here.

What could be the problem, what do I miss?

Comment: (I did not downvote), it's not looking for zones_count in your query but in your entity so you are gonna have to update your entity.

Comment: You could do use virtual property and use it in your index page, (filtering and sorting virtual property need to be done manually)

Comment: @DylanKAS and how can I add this virtual property? can you help me with this, can you send me a reference or an example link?

Comment: Have you tried using `$queryBuilder->addOrderBy('COUNT(z.site)', 'DESC');`? (And don't worry databases optimize the internal process, eliminating the need to count the site twice.)

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant no, but why should I? I want to sort by `zones_count`.

Comment: If you add `$queryBuilder->addOrderBy('COUNT(z.site)', 'DESC');` it will sort by the number of sites and this is the same as zone_count, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant of course it is not. Sites are entities, this is what I list on the admin page. `zones` are a field of `Site` entity, but that is a collection of `Zone` entities. `getZonesCount` what I need to show, and sort by, what is an aggregated in my query. Just check the code please.

Comment: I checked your code. you add a hidden alias site_count of 'count(z.site)'. I did a similar one but I sort with count(z.site) instead of the alias. My suggested method works on my Easyadmin backend . I don't know why you cannot reproduce it. Sorry.